# How can I wait for XHR?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to wait for the XHR to open after I continue with the program but synchronous XHR is deprecated in chrome api. How can I get around this?

Comment: possibly a duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) -- if you have concerns not addressed by that Q&A, please [edit] your question to clarify what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Using a callback to continue execution seems like the best method. Without a clear example of your project here's a generalized option:

```js
function performRequest() {
   // ... Some code

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("GET", "/bar/foo.txt", true);
   xhr.onload = function (e) {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        useRequest(xhr.responseText);
      }
   };
}


function useRequest(data) {
  // Continue with your application
}



performRequest();
```